# Laravel перенос

Tags: php, laravel

Будут ли проблемы если с локального хоста на хостинг так себе переносить сайт ларавел? Я изначально пытался на хосте делать все но увы композер и тд не работает тк как дешевый хост а подходящий стоит в 5 раз дороже( 
Вот и возник вопрос если сайт добью при всех(вояжер и тд) и после перенесу не будет ли проблем?

Comment: 50/50, как и вероятность встретить динозавра: вы либо встретите его, либо нет. Ваша проблема - это проблема окружения. Насколько совпадают конфиги PHP, версия PHP, все ли нужные модули PHP включены, правильно ли настроен веб-сервер. `phpinfo();` и дальше сравнивайте, думайте. `а подходящий стоит в 5 раз дороже` <= за 200 руб/мес можно 1Гб RAM KVM VDS взять. Или у вас шаред за 40?

Comment: вам ни кто не ответит на этот вопрос, просто попробуйте, далее решайте проблемы по мере их поступления.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для приложений на к примеру на symfony я думаю применимо и к laravel
На дешевых хостингах клиентов встречал примерно такие проблемы

1. Не запускается/не отрабатывает до конца composer

Решается ручным переносом папки vendor

2. Не генерится cache в symfony из-за memory_limit

Генерил на своем компе и опять же переносил вручную

3. Нельзя перенастроить директорию wwwroot, то есть можно настраивать только название файла

Можно попробовать решить симлинками

4. Не хватает каких либо модулей php

Решается через тех. поддержку, если не решается то такой хостинг точно нужно бросать

5. Не соответствует версия php

На многих хостингах есть выбор интерпретатора в настройках, как варинат момжно попросить чтобы вас перенесли на сервер со свежей версией. Опять же если хостер использует реально древнюю версию то лучше сменить хостера

Ну и самым универсальным вариантом остается как написали в комментариях к вопросу купить дешевый vds он будет в любом случае лучше чем shared